# Friend Function, expected Primary Expression before . token

Tags: c++, class, friend

So there are two classes in separate header files

Customer. h

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>

class Customer{
    friend void Display();
private:
    int number, zipCode;
public:
    Customer(int N, int Z){
    number = N;
    zipCode = Z;
    }
};
```

City. h
    using namespace std;
    #include 
    #include "Customer.h"

```
class City{
    friend void Display();
private:
    int zipCode;
    string city, state;
public:
    City(int Z, string C, string S){
        zipCode = Z;
        city = C;
        state = S;
    }
};
```

my main.cpp is as follows

```
#include "City.h"
#include "Customer.h"

void Display(){
        cout<<"Identification Number: "<<Customer.number<<endl
                <<"Zip Code: "<<Customer.zipCode<<endl
                <<"City: "<<City.city<<endl
                <<"State: "<<City.state<<endl;
    }


int main() {
    Customer A(1222422, 44150);
    City B(44150, "Woklahoma", "Kansas");

    Display();

}
```

I'm good with the basics of c++ but this is where I Don't understand, so my specific question is.... Why for the four lines of my Display function does the compiler tell me "error: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token"

Thanks in advance, Macaire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Customer` is a type. You need an object of that type to access it's `number` member (and the same for the rest of the lines).

You probably meant to take a `Customer` and `City` as arguments to `Display`:

```
void Display(Customer customer, City city){
    cout<<"Identification Number: "<<customer.number<<endl
            <<"Zip Code: "<<customer.zipCode<<endl
            <<"City: "<<city.city<<endl
            <<"State: "<<city.state<<endl;
}
```

Then pass your `Customer` and `City` objects to that function:

```
Display(A, B);
```

Comment: ouch yeah i see, I'm trying to access these fields as if they're static.

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to access data members from a class name

```
Customer.number
```

You cannot do that. You need a `Customer` instance:

```
Customer c;
std::cout << c.number;
```

You probably want to change `Display()` to

```
void Display(const Customer& c);
```

then use it like this:

```
Customer A(1222422, 44150);
Display(A);
```

and similarly for `City`.

Comment: Thanks I follow what you and sftrabbit said, and use a feature that I just learned about "Forward Declaration" and it all worked perfectly.